# Regex in lxml for python

Tags: python, regex, xpath, html-parsing

I having trouble implementing regex within xpath command. My goal here is to download the html contents of the main page, as well as the contents of all hyperlinks on the main page. However, the program throws exceptions because some of the href links do not connect to anything (ex. '//:javascript', or '#'). How would I use regex in xpath? Is there an easier way to except non-absolute hrefs?

```
from lxml import html
import requests
main_pg = requests.get("http://gazetaolekma.ru/")
with open("Sample.html","w", encoding='utf-8') as doc:
    doc.write(main_pg.text)
tree = html.fromstring(main_pg.content)
hrefs = tree.xpath('//a[re:findall("^(http|https|ftp):.*")]/@href')
for href in hrefs:
    link_page = requests.get(href)
    with open("%s.html"%href[0:9], "w", encoding ='utf-8') as href_doc:
        href_doc.write(link_page.text)
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use a regex like this? I guess you need an XPath `'//a[starts-with(@href, "http:") or starts-with(@href,"https:") or starts-with(@href,"ftp:")]/@href'`.

Comment: I know you can use regex in xpath, but I'm not entirely sure about syntax and what functions can be used within xpath. I searched for a while before posting and there is very limited documentation. Anyways thank you! Your answer works.

Comment: Please check what har07 suggests. If you find that answer working, too, I think you can accept that one. If not, I will post my workaround.

Comment: har07's solution throws this error: "All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters"

Comment: Ok, but I see Casimir already posted a solution closer to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with xpath 1.0 you can always use `or` in your predicate:

```
hrefs = tree.xpath('//a/@href[starts-with(., "http") or starts-with(., "ftp")]')
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html), `lxml` support EXSLT extension, which, in turn, support regex :

> lxml supports XPath 1.0, XSLT 1.0 and the EXSLT extensions through libxml2 and libxslt in a standards compliant way.

For example, using EXSLT [`re:test()`](http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/test/) function :

```
....
ns = {'re': 'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'}
hrefs = tree.xpath('//a[re:test(@href, "^(http|https|ftp):.*\b", "i")]/@href')
.....
```