# Using regex in xml etree parsing

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I need to parse xml file and find a values only starts with "123".
How i can do this using this code below?
It is possible to use regex inside this syntax?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
parse = ET.parse('xml.xml')
print([ events.text for record in parse.findall('.configuration/system/') for events in record.findall('events')])
```

xml.xml

```
<rpc-reply>
 <configuration>
        <system>
            <preference>
                <events>123</events>
                <events>124</events>
                <events>1235</events>                    
            </preference>
        </system>
 </configuration>
</rpc-reply>
```

Comment: For regex, it would be probably the best to operate on un-parsed (string) xml - just get `re.findall(r'>(123[^<]*)<', xml_string)` - gets this: `['123', '1235']`. Will get anything between `>` and `<` that starts with `123` and consists of any characters that are not `<` (because it should end the search, obviously).

Comment: @h4z3 yeah but, what if i only find those values inside <preference> tag or another?

Comment: Read about XPath use in `ET.findall`. XPath can do such filtering but you need to test what exactly you want. (Just play with it in the interactive console. I do that when I need something specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath predicate can do that much using built-in function `starts-with()`. But you need to use library that fully support XPath 1.0 such as [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/):

```
from lxml import etree as ET
raw = '''<rpc-reply>
 <configuration>
        <system>
            <preference>
                <events>123</events>
                <events>124</events>
                <events>1235</events>                    
            </preference>
        </system>
 </configuration>
</rpc-reply>'''
root = ET.fromstring(raw)
query = 'configuration/system/preference/events[starts-with(.,"123")]'
print([events.text for events in root.xpath(query)])
```

If you still want to use regex, `lxml` supports regex despite XPath 1.0 specification does not include regex (see: [Regex in lxml for python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850980/2998271)).

`xml.etree` only supports [limited subset of XPath 1.0](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) expression, which does not include `starts-with` function (and definitely does not support regex). So you need to rely on python string function to check that:

```
....
query = 'configuration/system/preference/events'
print([events.text for events in root.findall(query) if events.text.startswith('123')])
```